# How to click JavaScript prompt using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, automated-tests, puppeteer

Let's say I visit some website and then a **popup** comes, asking to allow my video. How do I select and make it `true`?

I tried the `await page.keyboard.press('Enter')` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What's the popup? Do you have the site?

Comment: @ggorlen popup means JS prompt. for ex:- prompt("hi ")

Comment: Thanks, but a runnable [mcve] of the site makes it much easier to help without guesswork and back-and-forth. That said, how does the posted answer not solve the problem exactly? (explain "not working" in more detail)

Comment: @ggorlen ok so, I was trying to bypass the popup on omegle.com video chat, where it asks us to allow audio and video.

Comment: Please [edit] that into the question and walk me step by step through what you're trying to accomplish. I have no idea how I can answer this until there's a clear cut goal, question, complete attempt, etc to work with, with as little ambiguity as possible. Thanks.

Comment: Have you find a solution for this ?

Comment: @wasilikoslow no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an event listener for dialogs:

```
page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
    await dialog.accept();
});
```

You can read the full documentation [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.5.0/docs/api.md#class-dialog).

Comment: not working. by popup, I mean a javascript prompt.